# The harmonic measure on the unit disc is absolutely continuous with respect to length

Tags: brownian-motion, harmonic-functions

I have read some pages from the book *Conformally Invariant Processes in the  Plane* by Lawler, and found there the following definition of a harmonic measure:
$$\text{hm}(z,D;V) = \mathbb{P}^z\left(B_{\tau_D}\in V\right)$$
(that is, the probability that a $d$-dimensional Brownian motion starting at $z$ is in $V$ the moment it hits the complement of $D$).

Later on, the book says that for the unit disc $\mathbb{D}$, it is obvious that the harmonic measure $\text{hm}(z,\mathbb{D};\cdot)$ is absolutely continuous (with respect to length).

Could you explain why is it so?

## Attempt

A possible interpretation of the claim is as follows: starting a Brownian motion at $z$, which is somewhere in the open disc $D$, the probability of exiting the disc via a set $A\subseteq\partial D$ whose (Lebesgue) measure is 0, is 0. That makes sense - when the "gate" is so small, one wouldn't expect to exit through it "by chance".

So the attempt is as follows: suppose otherwise. Let $A$ be a set with Lebesgue measure $0$, and let $a>0$ be its harmonic measure (for $z=0$). Now, turn the disc with angle $\theta$ such that $A$, and the turned $A^\theta$ are disjoint. (this is the part I'm not sure about - is that always possible?). Then, the harmonic measure of $A^\theta$ is also $a$. Now, do that enough ($k$) times so that $ka>1$, and that will lead to a contradiction.

## Update

The attempt above is wrong, as I may not necessarily have disjoint rotations of a 0-measured set. However, for $z=0$ it's not difficult to show that the harmonic measure of a set on the boundary is simply its normalized Lebesgue measure.

It's only left to see why it follows for $z\ne 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The density of the harmonic measure with respect to surface 
measure on the boundary is given by the [Poisson kernel.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel#On_the_ball) So
the result is true, but is there an easier argument that shows
that the result is "obvious"?

Here's my attempt.

Let $A$ be a subset of the boundary $\partial D$ of the disk 
$D=\{z: \|z\|< 1\}$ 
with zero Lebesgue (surface) measure, let 
$\tau=\inf\{t\geq 0: \|B_t\|\geq1\}$ be the hitting time of 
$D^c$ and define $h(z)=\mathbb{P}_z(B_\tau\in A)$ for $z\in D$. Then $h$ is harmonic on
$D$ and (as you've noted) $h(0)=0$. But by the [mean value property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#The_mean_value_property)
 of harmonic functions 
$$0=h(0)={1\over \omega_d}\int_D h(z)\,dz.$$ Because $h$ is non-negative, this means
$h(z)=0$ almost surely on $D$ with respect to
Lebesgue measure, and by continuity $h(z)=0$ for all $z\in D$.